# How to set a value in a simple schema equal to a previously determined variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, schema, database

I am making a meteor web app that uses some packages like simpleschema and collection 2 (both from aldeed).  I have made a schema where I need one of the values to be automatically set to a variable previously set by user input. I know I can use autovalue to do this, but it will not work. Here is my code for the schema.

```
CreateLobbySchema = new SimpleSchema({
  game: {
    type: String,
    label: "Game",
    autoValue: function(){
      return elementText
    },
    label: "Game"
  },
  console: {
    type: String,
    label: "Console"
  },
  players: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Players"
  },
  mic: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Mic"
  },
  note: {
    type: String,
    label: "Note"
  },
  gamertag: {
    type: String,
    label: "Gamertag"
  }
});
```

As you can see the first field has an autovalue that sets it to a variable. Meteor wont actually do anything with this though, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Are you not allowed to set this to a variable? If so what might I do to fix this?

Comment: And where is declaration of `elementText` variable?

Comment: @Sindis all this code is in the main.js file provided when starting a meteor app and the elementText variable is declared in between some script tags in an html file, which is imported using import "./templates/home.html"